# Keep fundamental type behavior with fixed size boost multiprecision integers

Tags: c++, boost-multiprecision

From the [cpp_int documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) :

> The type uses a sign-magnitude representation internally, so type int128_t has 128-bits of precision plus an extra sign bit. In this respect the behaviour of these types differs from fundamental (built-in) 2's complement types.

This behavior differs from fundamental types where the MSB indicates the sign.

In order to have a similar behavior to fundamental integers, the documentation proposes :

> In might be tempting to use a 127-bit type instead, and indeed this does work, but behaviour is still slightly different from a 2's complement fundamental (built-in) type as the minimum and maximum values are identical.

How can I keep the **exact** same behavior that fundamental types have but with fixed size boost multiprecision integers, such as `int512_t` ? If this isn't possible with boost, do you suggest any other library for doing so ?
Thanks.

Comment: The range of values representable by a sign-magnitude format and a 2's complement format are different, so you can't get the identical behavior of one format while using the other.